# Integrating legacy statistical packages in a R based workflow

Tags: r, workflow, legacy, emulation, knime

I am planning to run Monte Carlo simulations in an R environment (Windows 7). However I need to use old legacy statistical packages that are no longer executable in Windows 7, although I am aware that there are emulation solutions (Like VMWare) available. In addition I need to integrate these packages in a seamless workflow so that simulated data from R functions is pushed on the old package, processed, and pulled back for further analysis in R again.

I am aware that there are open source workflow tools (such as KNIME) that can integrate different software packages, but my internet searches tend to be swamped with references to WorkFlow Management software business applications that are irrelevant to me.

Is KNIME Analytics a suitable solution given my legacy software problem, and if not what workflow tool would you suggest?

Kind regards,

Giulio Flore

Comment: Apparently you don't mean R packages when you write about "statistical packages"?

Comment: That's correct. The packages are specialized statistical tools that were developed during the 1990s and early 2000s. Ther are all Windows based, but as Windows 7 has stopped supporting pre-7 OS releases I cannot even start the installation, let alone run them. Hence my basic workflow problem:

Comment: It might be time to bite the bullet and look for newer implementations.

Comment: KNIME is capable of executing [external programs](https://www.knime.org/files/nodedetails/_misc_External_Tool.html) with tabular output format and provide lots of nodes for transforming data (also for modelling, predicting, it has very good R integration). With its new server (non-free), you can even create REST services, so if the OS supported by KNIME, you can create customized services to R or other programs. (Worth noting the server version was not virtualization-friendly last time I checked.)